# How can I add the count of a character variable (year) to a barplot figure (with a defined x and y variable) in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2, count, bar-chart

I have created this barplot for the total number of cases in a year with each "Year" character representing a single study.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsvdp.png)

`histo$Year <-as.character(histo$Year) histo %>% ggplot(aes(x=Year,y=cases))+ geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.7, color="black", fill= "light blue")`

The table I have looks like this (up to 2016)

| Year | Cases |
| --- | --- |
| 1994 | 12 |
| 1996 | 1 |
| 1996 | 2 |
| 1996 | 6 |
| 1996 | 10 |
| 1997 | 3 |
| 1997 | 7 |

How do I add the number of each "Year" (which would be the number of studies in a given year) to the barplot (I would probably add then to the top of the bar or as a second x axis)?
I tried stat_count, but that does not like having a x and y variable in use.
I can define a 3rd column to in my original file and probably use that.

But I would like to learn an in R method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a stacked or grouped barplot? I think this might work:
https://r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2. I'd be interested to see if it works.
cheers
Candy

Comment: Hi Candy, I will give it a go. Though it is not precisely what I am looking for. I think so far the main alternative is using
histo1 <- histo %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(Year_count = n())
view (histo1) 
and then add a second x axis label